# Animate tspan x & y

Tags: css, svg

**CSS**

```
@keyframes moveText {
    0% {
        y:100;
    }
    100% {
        y:300;
    }
}

#Achieve tspan {
    animation:moveText 1s linear;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
```

**SVG**

```
<svg width:"300px" height:"300px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" version="1.1">
    <text id="Achieve" fill="#CCD1D9">
        <tspan x="100" y="264">Achieve</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```

I have SVG image that I want to animate. I want to move x=100 to x=300 yet I have tried everything (that I could think of) and nothing has worked.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `translation`:

```css
@keyframes moveText {
    100% {
        transform:translateY(200px);
    }
}

#Achieve {
    animation:moveText 1s linear;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
```

```html
<svg width="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300" version="1.1">
    <text id="Achieve" fill="#000" x="100" y="100">
        <tspan >Achieve</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: I don't know why I never thought of animated <text> ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SVG [animate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animate) element.

> I want to move x=100 to x=300

If you move the text to 300 it will appear out of the viewbox. You need to consider the width of the text.

Example

```html
<svg width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" version="1.1">
    <text id="Achieve" fill="#CCD1D9">
        <tspan x="200" y="264">Achieve
           <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="x" from="100" to="200"
        dur="1s" repeatCount="0"/></tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```